# different way to achive stylesheet_url

Tags: theme-development, css

I'd like to understand the difference between:

```
<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>
```

and

```
<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/style.css
```

because I think the second one is more flexible (is i decide to move the file in a subdirectory, for example. or if I have more stylesheet to add.. the second one seems smarter). Am I wrong?

In particular, where is `'stylesheet_url'` stored? and how to change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bloginfo('stylesheet_url')` will always return the current theme's stylesheet. If current theme is a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), for example, it will return `style.css` relative to the child theme's root rather than the parent theme's root.

`bloginfo('template_url')` will **always** return the parent theme's template directory URL. So using `<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/style.css` will always be the parent theme's stylesheet.

Since `bloginfo` echo's things out, I'm guessing you're not using the WordPress [enqueue system](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style), which you should be.  That is the most flexible. An end user wants to remove your stylesheet? Simple Just [dequeue it](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style).

That said, you *can* change the output of bloginfo via a filter.

To understand how this works you have to trace how `bloginfo` works. To start, `bloginfo` is a wrapper for [`get_bloginfo`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo). So let's take a look at that, the line relative to your question:

```
<?php
function get_bloginfo( $show = '', $filter = 'raw' ) {

    switch( $show ) {
        // snip snip

        case 'stylesheet_url':
            $output = get_stylesheet_uri();
            break;
        case 'stylesheet_directory':
            $output = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
            break;
        case 'template_directory':
        case 'template_url':
            $output = get_template_directory_uri();
            break;

                // snip snip
    }

    $url = true;
    if (strpos($show, 'url') === false &&
        strpos($show, 'directory') === false &&
        strpos($show, 'home') === false)
        $url = false;

    if ( 'display' == $filter ) {
        if ( $url )
            $output = apply_filters('bloginfo_url', $output, $show);
        else
            $output = apply_filters('bloginfo', $output, $show);
    }

    return $output;
}
```

And here's `bloginfo`.

```
<?php
function bloginfo( $show='' ) {
    echo get_bloginfo( $show, 'display' );
}
```

As you can see, the filter is always set to `display`, which means WP will use `apply_filters` on `get_bloginfo`'s output.

So to change things, you hook into either `bloginfo` or `bloginfo_url`. We want `bloginfo_url`.

```
<?php
add_filter('bloginfo_url', 'wpse76262_change_stylesheet', 10, 2);
function wpse76262_change_stylesheet($url, $show)
{
    if ('stylesheet_url' == $show) {
        $url = '/the/change/stylesheet.css';
    }

    return $url;
}
```

There are also filters in `get_stylesheet_uri`, `get_template_directory_uri`, and `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` that you could use as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are two differences between both methods:

1. `'stylesheet_url'` refers always to the directory of the current theme, be it a child theme or a parent theme. `'template_url'` is always just the parent theme.
2. `'stylesheet_url'` can be filtered by a plugin or a child theme. The filter is named `'stylesheet_uri'`. The combination of `'template_url'` and an appended string cannot be filtered. It is less flexible.

If you want to keep it flexible [enqueue the stylesheet](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/44821/73). Do not write a `link` element into the theme’s `header.php`.